# SPI Frame format of TPM1.2 Commands

Tags: tpm

- I have bought a TPM Chip: SLB9670.
- It can be communicated via the SPI Bus.
- What is the SPI frame format for firing TPM Commands with or
  without arguments. I have read the TPM Main Specifications documents 
  but haven't found much help. Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to crypto.SE. Beware that your question is only tangentially on-[topic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) because it asks how to use a particular device.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for could be in the [Data Sheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-SLB%209670VQ2.0-DataSheet-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4626fc1ce0b016fc78270350cd6#page=14) (be sure to read 5.5) for the hardware layer, or/and the [TCG PC Client Platform TPM Profile (PTP) Specification](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/resource/pc-client-platform-tpm-profile-ptp-specification/) for SPI frame format.

You'll also need to find out what commands to send. The specs are [there](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/resources/?categories=Specification&workgroups=Trusted%20Platform%20Module%20(TPM)&), and it is rumored that some have rewired their brain to actually use it (I'm not in). [More](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/resources/?workgroups=Trusted%20Platform%20Module%20(TPM)&).

Comment: thank you for the reply. The thing is that i have gone through the documents, but they have been of mere help. The confusion here is that Part-2 has structures define, and part-3 has API's, and even the API's which are defined aren't clear on how the arguments are passed, and the how do i (the micro-controller) call the TPM API's via the SPI bus? One way i know is by placing the values onto the SPI Bus which map onto the API's. So it's a lot of confusion, so if you can help me firing one command it would be of great help. And my application is a embedded systems application.

Comment: Normally you'd have a Field Applications Engineer at the manufacturer to answer questions like this.

Comment: @SAIPeregrinus thank you for the reply. Do you mean Infineon's Field Application engineer?? As the manufacturer of the TPM chip is infineon.

Comment: Yes, your company may already have one assigned, if not they have a customer support system to get one for help.